# Google Visualization explorer options won't have any effect after chart redraw

Tags: google-visualization

How can I keep zoom-in, zoom-reset functionality after chart redraw? It seems like these options stop working after I use zoom-in option and then redraw the chart. What am I missing? My code is:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','table']});

function drawChart(data, chartType) {
    var w = document.getElementById('chart_div').clientWidth;
    var h = w * 0.5;
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization[chartType](document.getElementById('chart_div'));  

    var columns = [];
    var series = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        //push default columns
        columns.push(i);
        if (i > 0) {
            series[i-1] = {};
        }
    }

    var options = {
        height: h,
        series: series,
        chartArea: {width: "65%", height: "65%"},
        legend: {textStyle: {fontSize: 12}},
        hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}, slantedTextAngle:80, format: 'yyy-MM-dd'},
        vAxis: {title: 'GUIDs'},
        explorer: {actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
             axis: 'horizontal',
             keepInBounds: true,
             maxZoom: 20}}

    function redraw() {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    window.addEventListener('resize', redraw, false);
    chart.draw(view, options);  
}
```

Comment: There is a bug.  Redrawing after exploring causes explore mode to be broken.  The only workaround is to rebuild the chart every time rather than merely redraw it.  This will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @dlaliberte do you know if this bug has been fixed or where I can find out more information?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the 'upcoming' release, but other problems still need to be fixed before we can release it as 'current'.  Releases are announced on the Release Notes page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes and on the google visualization api forum:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-visualization-api