# Can I disable/enable Scrolling in Google Chart with a Button?

Tags: jquery, scroll, google-visualization

I have a Google line chart on my site, which show the school grades of a student over the course of his school years. I have mouse wheel zooming enabled.

```
explorer: {
    axis: 'horizontal',
    maxZoomIn: 0.25,
    maxZoomOut: 4
},
```

Now I would like to give the user the possibility to disable scrolling with a button. Is it possible to remove the 'explorer' part or just disable scrolling through a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, let's start by moving the explorer option to a separate variable...

```
  var options = {
    pointSize: 4
  };

  var explorer = {
    axis: 'horizontal',
    maxZoomIn: 0.25,
    maxZoomOut: 4
  };
```

then we can enable explorer like so...

```
  options.explorer = explorer;
```

to disable...

```
  options.explorer = null;
```

keep in mind, anytime an option is changed, the chart needs to be re-drawn...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    pointSize: 4
  };

  var explorer = {
    axis: 'horizontal',
    maxZoomIn: 0.25,
    maxZoomOut: 4
  };

  $('#explorer-option').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#explorer-label').html() === 'Enable') {
      options.explorer = explorer;
      drawChart();

      $('#explorer-label').html('Disable');
      $('#explorer-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-circle-check');
      $('#explorer-icon').addClass('ui-icon-circle-close');
    } else {
      options.explorer = null;
      drawChart();

      $('#explorer-label').html('Enable');
      $('#explorer-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-circle-close');
      $('#explorer-icon').addClass('ui-icon-circle-check');
    }
  });

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');

  drawChart();
  function drawChart() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="explorer-option">
  <span id="explorer-icon" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"></span>&nbsp;<span id="explorer-label">Enable</span>
</button>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped alot. the only problem is, that it only works once :/

Comment: thanks, i forgot there is a bug with using explorer, the chart must be rebuilt to re-enable explorer, [see comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45764587/5090771) -- changed answer above, working now multiple times...

Comment: @WhiteHat can I reverse the scroll of the chart?